# Purpose of Metrizability

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, motivation

What is an example of when metrizability is used to prove a result? Or is metrizability of a more philosophical nature?

Answer (score 1):

[From a question on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93713/what-is-a-good-application-of-urysohns-theorem)

Some comments from the link mentioned above.

> A very remarkable and classical result that uses repeatedly the
>   Urysohn's lemma (not the metrization theorem) is the proof of Riesz
>   representation theorem in its general setting.

2.

> One good use is to conclude that the unit ball of the dual of a
>   separable Banach space, in the w*-topology, is a compact metric space.

3.

> This doesn't answer your question, but it's worth noting that the
>   proof of Urysohn's Theorem easily gives what Munkres calls the
>   Imbedding Theorem (34.2), since you end up imbedding X into some giant
>   RJ. This characterizes completely regular spaces as subspaces of
>   compact Hausdorff spaces. In turn, that theorem is used to prove the
>   Nagata-Smirnov metrization theorem, which actually classifies metric
>   spaces. To me, that's reason enough to develop Urysohn's theorem

4.

> The proof of Urysohn's metrization theorem provides you with a more or
>   less explicit metric coming from an embedding into a product space
>   (the metric looks similar to what I wrote in a comment to an answer)
>   and is related to what you described as a way to circumvent Urysohn's
>   theorem when proving metrizability of manifolds: if you can prove your
>   space to be Hausdorff, regular and second countable then you can write
>   down a metric for its topology.